# Transfering mysql/php code to PDO - what has replaced mysql_close($con)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am doing a long poll and so I want to shut off my connection to the database on every loop (about 1 minute loops).

I used to use mysql_close($con), so what do I use in PDO?

Also, when I was using mysql_query it seemed to return numbers as string, so when I returned them to my calling js via json it was still a string. But now, the PDO seems to actually return it as a number. Is this right?

Comment: the returned value of the js function should be a json object. whats PDO doing after that? show the code.

Comment: Yes, as long as the column is a numeric one. DB values will be cast to the appropriate php representation.

Comment: oh did u mean, when you used `mysql` it returned a string, and whn using `PDO` it returns the result as a number?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Thanks for the answers. I was just transfering over to PDO to help stop the hacking with database lookup, but it seems better in a load of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
     // use the connection here
     ...........

     // and now we're done; close it
      unset($db);
```

Comment: Maybe it's better unset($dbh); ?

Answer (score 1):

After a  successful connection to the database, an instance of the PDO class is returned to your script. The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

//just unset the variable:
unset($dbh);
//or
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: When you're entering code into a question or answer, you can enable syntax highlighting for it by highlighting it and clicking on the `{}` (curly brackets) button. This will make it easier for people to read.